# android.database.StaleDataException ScrollingFragment.java:234 Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed

Tags: java, android

This is the fragment activity on a music player. When I press the back button and the app plays on the background, the app crashes when I open it again. (attempt to invoke interface method "_____" on a null object reference) on Destroy is what Android Studio is showing me.

[screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oj9e.png)

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    //int textLimit = 26;
    if (data != null && data.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            long id = data.getLong(data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
            long duration = data.getLong(data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION));
            String title = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            String artist = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            String album = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
            long albumid = data.getLong(data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
            songMainArrayList.add(new Song(id, duration,album, title, artist, AppConstants.getAlbumArtUri(albumid), false));
        }
        while (data.moveToNext());
        data.close();
    }
```

I'm not sure what might be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is due to the fact that you're closing the cursor in the `onLoadFinished` method, and it's not being managed properly when your fragment is being destroyed. When your fragment gets recreated after being in the background, you're trying to access the closed cursor, resulting in the "attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference" error.

To fix this issue, you need to ensure that you don't close the cursor when it's still needed by your fragment. Here's how you can modify your code to manage the cursor lifecycle correctly:

1. Initialize your `songMainArrayList` as a global variable in your Fragment, so it's accessible throughout the fragment's lifecycle:

```java
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private ArrayList<Song> songMainArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    // ...
}
```

2. In your `onLoadFinished` method, don't close the cursor immediately after populating your `songMainArrayList`. Instead, store a reference to the cursor, and Android will automatically manage the cursor lifecycle for you:

```java
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    // Clear the list to avoid duplicates when the loader reloads data.
    songMainArrayList.clear();

    if (data != null && data.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            long id = data.getLong(data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
            long duration = data.getLong(data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION));
            String title = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            String artist = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            String album = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
            long albumid = data.getLong(data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
            songMainArrayList.add(new Song(id, duration, album, title, artist, AppConstants.getAlbumArtUri(albumid), false));
        } while (data.moveToNext());

        // Don't close the cursor here; it will be automatically managed by the Loader.
    }

    // Update your UI with the songMainArrayList.
    // ...
}
```

With this approach, the cursor will be managed automatically by the `LoaderManager`, and you don't need to worry about explicitly closing it. Just make sure to clear your `songMainArrayList` at the beginning of `onLoadFinished` to avoid duplicates when the loader reloads data.

By making these changes, you should be able to avoid the "attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference" error when your fragment is recreated after being in the background.